# Did the Titan II GLV execute a roll program?

Tags: titan-rocket

I'm working on an edit for the Wikipedia article on the roll program that some rockets used when getting into orbit. I found a good reference for the Saturn V, but the article's original authors claim that the Titan II rolled as well. I haven't been able to find anything that confirms or denies that.  Did it execute a roll program at launch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I believe so. The first reference I found was a transcript of [Jim McDivitt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_McDivitt)'s [presentation to the Society of Experimental Test Pilots](http://web.mit.edu/digitalapollo/Documents/Chapter4/geminimanned.pdf) where he narrated a film of an unmanned Gemini flight (bold is mine):

> This will be a little faster than normal time. There's ignition! You can see the first-stage tank pressures coming down. **We've got the roll program where the booster is aligning us up with the flight path.** Now we've started the pitch program. These are rate needles here.

Here's another mention, from ["Gemini Flies!"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-3-319-68142-9%2F1.pdf), referring to Gemini 3:

> Just two seconds into the mission, Grissom reported that the onboard clock had started. This was followed ten seconds later by confirmation that **the vehicle had begun its planned roll program** and then by the pitch over at T+25 seconds.

Comment: Very handy, thank you.  I suppose that since the Titan II was an ICBM finding more than this might be challenging.  I was able to find a reference to the Saturn V that explained even the circuits involved in the roll program.